# What is causing this bizarre EntityFramework behavior wth nullable dates?

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, entity-framework-6

I have run into an EF problem so bizarre that it's taken me a whole day to believe it enough to pose the question.

I've got a table with many fields, but the relevant ones are

```
PlayerId int not null
TeamId int not null
GameDate date null
```

There are many players in the table, each with a team and game date. For simplicity, say there are two players `PLAYER1, PLAYER2`, and there are 3 games with dates `DATE_P1_G1, DATE_P1_G2..., DATE_P3_G3` (They are real dates, but I don't think the date values are relevant, so I'm keeping it abstract.) Thus there are 6 rows in the table.

Consider this query:

```
Dim playersByTeam = db.PlayerGames.
       Where(Function(x) x.TeamId = {VALUE}).
       ToList()
```

along with debugging code:

```
For Each item In playersByTeam
    Debug.WriteLine($"{item.PlayerId} {item.GameDate}")
Next
```

This produces the expected result:

```
PLAYER1 DATE_P1_G1
PLAYER1 DATE_P1_G2
PLAYER1 DATE_P1_G3
PLAYER2 DATE_P2_G1
PLAYER2 DATE_P2_G2
PLAYER2 DATE_P3_G2
```

But then I add a simple sort on the (non-nullable) PlayerId:

```
Dim playersByTeam = db.PlayerGames.
       Where(Function(x) x.TeamId = {VALUE}).
       OrderBy(Function(x) x.PlayerId).
       ToList()
```

This produces the **wrong** output:

```
PLAYER1 DATE_P1_G1
PLAYER1 DATE_P1_G1
PLAYER1 DATE_P1_G1
PLAYER2 DATE_P2_G1
PLAYER2 DATE_P2_G1
PLAYER2 DATE_P2_G1
```

In other words, it pulls each player record, but **picks the date from one of them and assigns it to all rows for that player**.

As a test, I made the game date column non-nullable and *then it produces the correct behavior*!

What could be causing that?!

Comment: Post an *actual*, reproducible example, including the actual schema,  relations, entities and mappings. EF doesn't change data nor does it mix single objects like this. At least, use SQL Server Profiler and check what gets sent to the server. Most likely the wrong data was stored, or you are using joins that aren't visible in the question.

Comment: Most likely what is causing this is not shown here. However, as always in such cases, start with logging queries generated by EF (db.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine or similar). Then attach the output for both cases (or not, because you are quite likely to figure it out yourself after doing this).